# React Async Select bug on mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am making a website with react as the frontend framework. In one of the forms I used Async react-select to display a couple of the fields. This works well on desktop but on mobile it shows it as the first picture. In essence, all styling is messed up and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help? Here are all the things i think are relevant.

#### package.json

I use bulma for my styling

```
"react-select": "^5.7.4",
```

#### FormSheet.tsx

Please assume that the callback functions passed in as props and options work the way they are intended. This is purely a styling issue.

```
....
return (<div className="columns is-centered">
        <div className={"column is-half"} style={{}}>
          <form
            style={{
              marginBottom: "15px",
              padding: "10px",
            }}
          >
            <div className="field lid">
              <label className="label">Lid</label>
              <div className="control">
                <AsyncSelect
                  id="id_owner"
                  name="owner"
                  required
                  loadOptions={loadOptionsLeden}
                  value={
                    optionsLeden?.find((x) => x.value === decla.owner) ||
                    convertLeden([
                      leden?.find((l) => l.id === decla.owner) as LedenModel,
                    ])
                  }
                  defaultOptions={convertLeden(leden)}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setDecla({ ...decla, owner: e?.value as number });
                  }}
                  noOptionsMessage={() => "Geen opties"}
                  loadingMessage={() => "Loading"}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field evenement">
              <label className="label">Evenement:</label>
              <div className="control">
                <AsyncSelect
                  id="id_event"
                  name="event"
                  value={decla.event && convertEvents([decla.event])}
                  defaultOptions={optionsEvents}
                  required
                  onFocus={() => loadOptionsEvents("")}
                  loadOptions={loadOptionsEvents}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setDecla({
                      ...decla,
                      event:
                        events.find((ev) => ev.id === e?.value) ||
                        ({} as EventModel),
                    });
                  }}
                  noOptionsMessage={() => "Geen Evenementen"}
                  loadingMessage={() => "Loading"}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="field aanwezig">
              <label className="label">Aanwezig</label>
              <div className="control">
                <AsyncSelect
                  isMulti
                  required
                  name="present"
                  id="id_present"
                  onFocus={() => loadOptionsLeden("")}
                  loadOptions={loadOptionsLeden}
                  defaultOptions={optionsLeden.sort((a, b) => {
                    return a.value - b.value;
                  })}
                  value={
                    optionsLeden?.filter((x) =>
                      decla?.present?.includes(x.value)
                    ) ||
                    convertLeden(
                      leden?.filter((x) => decla?.present?.includes(x.id))
                    )
                  }
                  onChange={async (e) => {
                    if (e.some((val) => val?.value === -1)) {
                      const non_reunist = await GET_leden("page_all");
                      setDecla({
                        ...decla,
                        present: non_reunist?.map((x) => x?.id) as number[],
                      }); // change the value going to the API
                      setOptionsLeden((options) => [
                        ...options.filter(
                          (i) => !non_reunist.map((x) => x.id).includes(i.value)
                        ),
                        ...convertLeden(non_reunist),
                      ]);
                    } else {
                      setDecla({
                        ...decla,
                        present: e?.map((x) => x?.value as number),
                      }); // change the value going to the API
                    }
                  }}
                  noOptionsMessage={() => "Geen opties"}
                  loadingMessage={() => "Loading"}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>)
```

The first and second pictures are how it is on my iPhone when I test it both prior to focus and before selecting anything. The third is how it should be.

Again this is only a problem that I see on mobile. (I use safary on my iPhone).

Thanks for your help in advance.

[image: messed up select options]

[image: messed up multiple options]

[image: correct format]